# Apply where condition only to one occurrence

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm building search functionality for my app. To simplify things:
there are two tables: shops and subscriptions

Each shop can have multiple subscription records, subscription has field `expires_at`.  Now, I assume that shop has active subscription if subscription exsists and at least one of shop's subscripion expires_at date is bigger than now().

It is one of the conditions to the whole query. Here is code:

```php
$shops = Shop::when($subscription, function($query, $subscription) {
    $query->doesntHave('subscriptions')->orWhereHas('subscriptions', function($q) use ($subscription, $query) {
        $query->where('expires_at', '<', now());
    });
});
```

It doesn't work as expected because if i.e. shop has three related subscriptions and at least one of them is expired – it assumes that shop has no active subscription (even though it has).

I would need to implement some nested function inside or whereHas, I guess, to sort by expires_at desc and then limit to one and only then pass where expires_at clause, however I've no idea how.

And I rather need to stick with Eloquent Query Builder rather than DB facade or raw sql.

Basically, it is the same problem what wasn't answered here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/latest-record-from-relationship-in-wherehas?page=1

Comment: Do you want to include shops which don't have subscriptions also?

Comment: Yes, all shops who has no active subscription (null or expired).

Comment: why you use when ?

Comment: Because I have multiple conditions when to apply given query. As far as I know, "when" doesn't affect query itself

Comment: i posted an answer check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some tries in raw sql I figured it out:

```php
$query->select('shops.*')
    ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'shops.id', 'subscriptions.shop_id')
    ->whereNull('subscriptions.id')
    ->orWhere('subscriptions.expires_at', '<', now())
    ->where('subscriptions.id', function($q) {
        $q->select('id')
            ->from('subscriptions')
            ->whereColumn('shop_id', 'shops.id')
            ->latest('expires_at')
            ->limit(1);
    });
```

It is not only faster than where exists clause but also gives me what I needed – only the "highest" subscription for given shop is under consideration.

Comment: nice but its not either where null or where it expires_at < now() not both combined if you want them combined ->where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereNull('subscriptions.id')
          ->orWhere('subscriptions.expires_at', '<', now())
});

Comment: Actually it is. I was testing output both with combined query and without, effect is exactly the same (in the matter of pure sql, this change is irrelevant in this scenario). It returns all the shops it should be returning.

Comment: i think it will never return a shop with subscriptions.id null https://laraveldaily.com/and-or-and-brackets-with-eloquent/

Comment: It does. 
`select * from table where a is null or b = 1 and c = 0` is exactly the same what 
`select * from table where a is nulll or (b=1 and c=0)`. 

After all, I've the working code and I clearly see that it returns both: shops without subscription relation at all and shops which highest subscription is expired.

Comment: In a little more complex scenario, like the article you posted it would be necessary to put brackets tho. In my case, where there is only one condition on the left and two on right, it is fine both ways.

Comment: it not same query but for now same results yes i know sql optimizer is great but i think the last part will run when it is null too i wish you good fortune in the queries to come

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$shops = Shop::doesntHave('subscriptions')->orWhereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('expires_at', '<', now());
})->get();
```

Comment: Doesn't really work, it still has the same problem as above – lists shops even though they have at least one active sub.

Comment: Do you need shops which have at least on active sup or the opposite just list shops which don't have any active sup? Also, do you check **expires_at** contents and what if apply condition you want or not?

Comment: I need both, however active are easy. In this case, I need to properly get only shops with unactive (or without at all) subscriptions (which doesn't have ANY active ones)

Comment: I modified my answer. check if that's what you want.

Comment: I have no possibility to test it now, however I already see that it won't solve the issue. It is almost the same what I put in the question, date function is not necessary here. Effect will be same as I described in my solution :(

Comment: Sorry about that. probably I didn't understand you quite enough.

Comment: Np. :-) The thing is, that if shop has 3 subs, one active, and two expired - given query will count this shop as unactive sub (because at least one of related subs is expired, so condition is met). There is need for some sorting and limiting / grouping, however I do not know how to apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$shops = Shop::WhereHas('subscriptions')->withCount('subscriptions as 
   active_subscriptions_count' => function ($query) {
          $query->where('expires_at', '<', now());
        }])->having('active_subscriptions_count', '>=', 3)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input :-)
It doesn't work, still – condition in your query is wrong. Number "3" is random. Sometimes it is 1 and sometimtes in can be 10. 

Before calling `$query->where('expires_at', '<', 'now()` should be some limiting/grouping function so this where clause is applied ONLY to newset subscription

Comment: get me the shops that has subscriptions are not expired and count is 3 or more what  is your query goal from this ?

Comment: Check up my answer – I got the solution :-) Perhaps that will make you better understand what my goal was.
Cheers!